# Start the numbers in new column from last highest numbers in another column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, max

We are trying to get 'Expected Output' start from the highest number from 'Doc_number' grouped by 'Roll_NO'.

| Roll_NO | Doc_number | Expected Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 171 | 2 | 8 |
| 171 | 3 | 9 |
| 171 | 4 | 10 |
| 171 | 5 | 11 |
| 171 | 6 | 12 |
| 171 | 7 | 13 |
| 181 | 2 | 7 |
| 181 | 3 | 8 |
| 181 | 4 | 9 |
| 181 | 5 | 10 |
| 181 | 6 | 11 |
| 183 | 2 | 5 |
| 183 | 3 | 6 |
| 183 | 4 | 7 |

How to pass max to to the next column and start from that number?

Comment: have you tried anything yet? what challenges are you facing in your attempts? to give you an idea, you can just calculate max of the doc number field for every roll_no group and then use it further.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using window functions.

Initial df:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(171, 2),
     (171, 3),
     (171, 4),
     (171, 5),
     (171, 6),
     (171, 7),
     (181, 2),
     (181, 3),
     (181, 4),
     (181, 5),
     (181, 6),
     (183, 2),
     (183, 3),
     (183, 4)],
    ['Roll_NO', 'Doc_number']
)
```

Script:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w_desc = W.partitionBy('Roll_NO').orderBy(F.desc('Doc_number'))
w_asc = W.partitionBy('Roll_NO').orderBy('Doc_number')
df = df.withColumn('output', F.max('Doc_number').over(w_desc) + F.row_number().over(w_asc))

df.show()
# +-------+----------+------+
# |Roll_NO|Doc_number|output|
# +-------+----------+------+
# |    171|         2|     8|
# |    171|         3|     9|
# |    171|         4|    10|
# |    171|         5|    11|
# |    171|         6|    12|
# |    171|         7|    13|
# |    181|         2|     7|
# |    181|         3|     8|
# |    181|         4|     9|
# |    181|         5|    10|
# |    181|         6|    11|
# |    183|         2|     5|
# |    183|         3|     6|
# |    183|         4|     7|
# +-------+----------+------+
```