# How to increment the value by one if the value of the column is not there in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a below pyspark dataframe

```
a = [["1","fawef"],["","esd"],["","rdf"],["2","ddbf"]]
columns = ["id","name"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = a, schema = columns)
```

```
id      name
1       fawef
        esd
        rdf
2       ddbf
```

Now my requirement is, if the id column is empty then I need to get the max of the id and increment that value by 1 and place the value in new column of the particular row.

Example:
In the above dataframe second row is empty in the id column now i need to get the max of id column that will be `2` and now i need to add `1` to the max value now the output will be `3`. Now i need to place 3 in the second row of the new column.

output i am expecting

```
id      name     new_col
1       fawef    1
        esd      3
        rdf      4
2       ddbf     2
```

Is there any way to achieve the above output, it will be great.

Comment: is there anything that you've tried that did not work?

Comment: df = df.withColumn("update_col",F.when(df["id"].isNull(),col("id")).otherwise(df["id"]) ) trying with this but not working

Comment: what you're trying is, in plain English - *use value of `id` column in case the `id` column is null. If `id` column is not null, use value from `id` column*. So, you're effectively just using `col('id')` with extra (unnecessary) steps that do nothing.

Comment: in the expected output, what is the expected order of name while incrementing max of `id`?

Comment: name will not matter here, if the id is null then get the max value and increment by 1, if the id is not null retain the same id in the new column

Comment: you seem to know what you require, have you tried anything in this regard that did not work?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72121980/8279585) is a similar question that has an answer

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing it will be easy if we have the max of the `id` field and a `row_number()` wherever the `id` field is blank.

I used the following data

```
# +----+----+
# |  id|name|
# +----+----+
# |   1|blah|
# |null| yes|
# |null|  no|
# |   2|bleh|
# |null|ohno|
# +----+----+
```

and, did the following transformations

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('id_rn', func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy(func.lit('1')))). \
    withColumn('new_id', 
               func.when(func.col('id').isNull(), func.max('id').over(wd.partitionBy(func.lit('1'))) + func.col('id_rn')).
               otherwise(func.col('id'))
               ). \
    show()

# +----+----+-----+------+
# |  id|name|id_rn|new_id|
# +----+----+-----+------+
# |null| yes|    1|     3|
# |null|  no|    2|     4|
# |null|ohno|    3|     5|
# |   1|blah|    1|     1|
# |   2|bleh|    1|     2|
# +----+----+-----+------+
```

- I created a new field to assign row numbers or some ID to the blank values using `row_number()`
- I used the aforementioned to add it to the max of `id` field whenever `id` is blank